# on macos , repaired disk errors keep returning, do I need a new Mac?

Tags: mac, ssd

I'm trying to figure out if I need to replace my 2018 Mac Mini purchased in Dec 2019. (512 GB SSD, 16 GB RAM). I keep getting the following error when I run First Aid. I repair it in Recovery Mode from the bottom up, first the volume and then the container and it says it is repaired and the disk looks ok but then a few hours when I run First Aid again the error has returned:

```
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Checking snapshot 11 of 12 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-07-08-182610.local)
/dev/rdisk1s1: warning: mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (-1) for extent (75965840 + 4)
/dev/rdisk1s1: warning: mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (-1) for extent (76696330 + 8)
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Checking snapshot 12 of 12 (com.apple.TimeMachine.2023-07-08-192548.local)
/dev/rdisk1s1: error: mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (75965840 + 4)
/dev/rdisk1s1: error: mismatch between extentref entry reference count (0) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (1) for extent (76696330 + 8)
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Checking the document ID tree.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Checking the fsroot tree.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Checking the extent ref tree.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Verifying volume object map space.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Verifying allocated space.
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** Performing deferred repairs.
/dev/rdisk1s1: error: Unable to perform deferred repairs without full space verification
/dev/rdisk1s1: error: Try running fsck against the entire APFS container instead of a volume
/dev/rdisk1s1: ** The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 could not be verified completely.
/dev/rdisk1s1: Sat Jul  8 20:09:48 2023
```

From smartmontools I see:

```
smartctl -a disk0
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [Darwin 22.5.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD AP0512M
Serial Number:                      C078504002HJRFYAB
Firmware Version:                   1296.120
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x106b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Local Time is:                      Sun Jul  9 20:22:36 2023 ADT
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0004):   Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x0004):     DS_Mngmt
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     0.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        49 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    11%
Data Units Read:                    355,382,704 [181 TB]
Data Units Written:                 237,678,387 [121 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 7,371,234,957
Host Write Commands:                3,890,298,980
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       449
Power On Hours:                     4,191
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   277
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read 1 entries from Error Information Log failed:
GetLogPage failed: system=0x38, sub=0x0, code=745

bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the exact make and model or your Mac? Have you upgraded the Mac? If so, how?

Comment: Did you try what DFA suggested (i.e. running against the whole container, not just the volume)? If so, what did it say when you did that? If you haven't tried it, why not?

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that I did run against the whole container as DFA suggests, that it then says the disk is repaired and looks ok, but then a few hour later if I run DFA again the error has returned. Also added details on my Mac which has never been upgraded.

Comment: Do you need to replace an entire mac because of a potential SSD issue?!

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I wondered that too. However, it appears the 2018 Mac Mini's drive is soldered to the mainboard: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/replace-internal-ssd-in-mac-mini-2018.2339501/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not replace my 2018 Mac Mini. It seems that this may have been a bug in MacOS or First Aid as I no longer get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error and did some research on it that I thought I'd share here. An important distinction is that this relates to drives formatted as APFS. Be careful about following advice you find that may be older and not specific to APFS drives.

- Several references (recent) point to the need in APFS drives to run First Aid on the container, not the volume. This apparently needs to be done while the system is not mounted, like in recovery mode (Command R at startup). [Link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mismatch-extentref-entry-reference-count.2329494/)
- One user says that he manually unmounts the drive prior to running First Aid, claiming that Disk Utility sometimes fails to do so. [Link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mismatch-extentref-entry-reference-count.2329494/post-30740836)
- Another user in same MacRumors discussion (with 68000 identity points) says that he not only ran First Aid 'all instances' of his Master drive, but disabled Time Machine and then used Terminal to delete all local snapshots.[Link](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mismatch-extentref-entry-reference-count.2329494/post-30741890)
- This Apple Support doc discusses viewing and deleting your APFS snapshots. [Link](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/disk-utility/dskuf82354dc/mac)

**Drive health vs data corruption**

- The issues that I've been seeing related to this appear to be mostly related to data corruption, not due to drive failure, even though the error messages seem quite ominous. That said, reformatting your drive to resolve corruption issues is not insignificant, even if you have a recent backup.
- This post refers to *smartmon tools* as a free command line APFS disk monitoring/evaluation solution. [Link](https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/checking-the-health-of-your-macs-drive-s/25546)
- Another post refers to a free GUI-based SSD monitor called SSDReporter. [Link](https://www.corecode.io/ssdreporter/)

**Ran smartctl from smartmon tools**

```
josh@joshuas-mini ~ % smartctl -a disk3s5
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [Darwin 22.5.0 arm64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD AP1024Q
Serial Number:                      0ba0122c40a52e0b
Firmware Version:                   874.120.
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x106b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               3
Local Time is:                      Wed Jul 26 08:06:52 2023 CDT
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0004):   Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x0004):     DS_Mngmt
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     0.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        33 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    10%
Data Units Read:                    653,815,670 [334 TB]
Data Units Written:                 495,164,729 [253 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 12,687,340,931
Host Write Commands:                6,148,184,985
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       225
Power On Hours:                     5,760
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   79
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read 1 entries from Error Information Log failed: GetLogPage failed: system=0x38, sub=0x0, code=745
```